# Add a comma to every curly bracket except the last curly bracket in Shell/awk/sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I'd like to add a comma after } except the last one } Tried Google but can't find the answer.

**Example as below:**

From

```
{
  "{#SERVICES} ,": "Directory",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
}
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "krb5kdc",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
}
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "kadmin",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
}
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "named",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
}
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "httpd",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
}
```

To

```
{
  "{#SERVICES} ,": "Directory",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
},
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "krb5kdc",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
},
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "kadmin",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
},
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "named",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
},
{
  "{#SERVICES}": "httpd",
  "{#STATUS}": "RUNNING"
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!!

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @stduong2210 : Use a text editor which can do multiline search&replace (or a tool like `sed`) and replace every `}\n{` by `},\n{`.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '}\n{' 'BEGIN { RS="" } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (i==NF) { str=$i } else { str=$i"},\n{" };printf "%s",str} print "\n" }'
```

Set the field separator to "}\n{" and the record separator to "" and then loop on each field printing the field followed by "},\n{" apart from the last field where we simply print the field.

Comment: No problem. If the solution meets your requirement, please take the time to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed`:

```
sed -E ':l;N;$!bl; s/}\n\{/},\n\{/g' example.txt
```

- The first command sequence `:l;N;$!bl;` slurps whole lines in the pattern space.
- We would like to just say `s/}\n{/},\n{/g` but the left curly braces require
  escapes as above.

With `POSIX sed` (also with `bash`):

```
sed -E ':l;N;$!bl; s/}'\$'\n''\{/},'\\$'\n''\{/g' example.txt
```

- The POSIX sed does not accept the expression `\n` then we need to once
  terminate the single-quoted block, put the newline character as `$'\n'`
  (with a help of `bash` quoting), then restart another single-quoted block.

BTW if `perl` happens to be your option, you can say:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/}\n\{/},\n\{/g' example.txt
```

- The `-0777` option tells perl to slurp all lines at first.

Comment: Thank you for the reply message. If you feel comfortable with any of the answers (Raman Sailopal's or mine), would you please accept one by clicking on the check mark beside the answer? BR.